# Expression not correctly identified ( Operators and Operands )

Tags: javascript, java, regex, grails, groovy

I need to identify top-level expression from a given string and convert it into the left operand, right operand and operator in groovy.

I have created a matcher array to match expression and logic is as follow

```
        static CONDITION_REGEXPS = [
            '(.+) (==) (.+)',
            '(.+) (!=) (.+)',
            '(.+) (>) (.+)',
            '(.+) (>=) (.+)',
            '(.+) (<) (.+)',
            '(.+) (<=) (.+)'
    ]

       static fromString(def string) {
        if (string) {
            string = string.split('\\|\\|');

            List<List> list = string.collect({
                it.trim().replaceAll(/^\(|\)$/, '').split('&&').collect({ condition ->
                    condition = condition.trim()
                    def regex = CONDITION_REGEXPS.find({ condition.matches(it) })
                    if (regex) {
                        return [leftOperand: condition.replaceFirst(regex, '$1'), operator: condition.replaceFirst(regex, '$2'), rightOperand: condition.replaceFirst(regex, '$3')]
                    }
                })
            })
            return list
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
```

Now I am passing string into following function,

```
def str = '( ${a < b ? a : b} < ${a > b ? a : b} )'

println fromString(str);
```

Which given me wrong result,

```
leftOperand: ${a < b ? a : b} < ${a
operator: >
rightOperand: b ? a : b}
```

Which is wrong, it should be,

```
leftOperand: ${a < b ? a : b}
operator: < 
rightOperand: ${a > b ? a : b}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are probably going to need to write your parser so that it avoids regular expressions and split

Comment: Agree with @tim_yates; what you're trying to parse is not regular (depth matters, and you have no fixed limit on depth) and so you can't safely write a regular expression to parse it.  If you know that your input will always be '(${...} OPERATOR ${...})' then you could work with that but it's not clear from your question what the restrictions on the input are.