# Regex for divide expression in LHS / RHS and operator

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I want to divide expression with the `>` operator. I want to identify any expression that used `>` operator and divide it into three groups: `LHS, RHS and >`

I am using the following regex

```
(.+)(>)(.+)
```

I wrongly identify the group

```
5 > ${a > 0 ? a :6 }
```

It retrieves

```
Group1: 5 > ${a
Group2: >
Group3: 0 ? a :6 }
```

Which is **wrong**, **it should retrieve**

```
Group1: 5
Group2: >
Group3: ${a > 0 ? a :6 }
```

Any suggestion to make it work. Can I add something in Regex that should ignore `>` operator which is used inside `${}`

Comment: You are probably going to need to write your parser so that it avoids regular expressions and split https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796886/expression-not-correctly-identified-operators-and-operands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add something in Regex that should ignore `>` operator which is used inside `${}`:

You may be able to use this regex that skips `>` inside `{...}` (assuming there are no unbalanced and escaped parentheses).

```
(\${[^}]+}|[^>]+?)\h*>(?![^{}]*})\h*(.+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jYkSfL/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\${[^}]+}|[^>]+?)`: Group 1: Match a string that is `${...}` format or 1+ of any character that is not `>`
- `\h*>`: Match 0 or more whitespaces followed by a `>`
- `(?![^{}]*})\h*`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a `}` ahead without a `{` and `}`.
- `(.+)`: Group 2: Match remaining characters

Comment: What if I want to ignore any operator from (<, >, =, =>, =<) between ${ }

Comment: For that you can check this updated regex https://regex101.com/r/jYkSfL/3